# How to get name of enumeration in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've got this model with a static enumeration set

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.RefreshableComponent', {
   statics: {
      RefreshIntervals: {
         ONEMIN: 1,
         FIVEMINS: 2,
         TENMINS: 3,
         FIFTEENMINS: 4,
         DEFAULT: 5
      }
   }
});
```

and I'm accessing it in another class like so

```
updateDefaultTask: function () {
   this.updateTask(MyApp.model.RefreshableComponent.RefreshIntervals.DEFAULT);
},
updateTask: function (refreshInterval) {
      var components = this.getVisibleComponentsByRefreshInterval(refreshInterval);
      if (this.debugMode) {
         console.log("REFRESHMANAGER: Triggered the update task " + refreshInterval);
      }    
   },
```

I would like to display the name of the refreshInterval in the log, not the int value. How can I go about this?

I'm open to defining this enumeration in a different way, as long as I can still pass in the name as a parameter, rather than the int, for readability reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ext has the [Ext.Object.getKey()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Object-method-getKey) method:

> Returns the first matching key corresponding to the given value. If no
>   matching value is found, null is returned.

```
var person = {
    name: 'Jacky',
    loves: 'food'
};

alert(Ext.Object.getKey(person, 'food')); // alerts 'loves'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose instead of using an Enumeration in it's traditional sense, you could store a collection of key value pair objects like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.RefreshableComponent', {
   statics: {
      RefreshIntervals: {
         ONEMIN: { value = 1, name = 'ONEMIN' },
         FIVEMINS: { value = 2, name = 'FIVEMINS' },
         TENMINS: { value = 3, name = 'TENMINS' },
         FIFTEENMINS: { value = 4, name = 'FIFTEENMINS' },
         DEFAULT: { value = 5, name = 'DEFAULT' }
      }
   }
});
```

The you could reference them like this:

```
updateDefaultTask: function () {
   this.updateTask(MyApp.model.RefreshableComponent.RefreshIntervals.DEFAULT.name);
}
```

and if you needed the int value:

```
updateDefaultTask: function () {
   this.updateTask(MyApp.model.RefreshableComponent.RefreshIntervals.DEFAULT.value);
}
```

It's perhaps a little more verbose, but is a little more flexible as you could expand the objects if there is a need over time. Perhaps they have an associate icon image or something similar you might need to accommodate for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is a valid alternative and will keep that in mind for the future.